# Getting below error while executing update or delete methods for repeated rows in database by using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am very new to **hibernate**. I am using a code which will insert data into database, retrive, update or delete rows for the table using hibernate annotations. But update and delete methods are not working when I am updating an existing record in the table for more than one time and same case for delete also. sample table is and its corresponding codes are shown below.

```
Table:
cnt_Id  t   mode        cntNum           cntType
12345       rail        cnt12345         rectangle
48956       ROAD        CNTR08112013     circle
12345       ocean       cnt478569        square
```

In the above table, I am able to update row having `cnt_Id:48956` but I am getting the following error while updating for `cnt_Id:12345`.

error info:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: **More than one row with the given identifier was found**: 12345, for class: def.ContwithAnnotations
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:69)
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:42)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2992)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:395)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:375)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:139)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:195)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:103)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:878)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:815)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:808)
at abc.HBSubclass.deleteContainer(HBSubclass.java:130)
at def.ContMain.main(ContMain.java:102)
```

ContwithAnnotations code:

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="Test13")
public class ContwithAnnotations {
@Id

private int cnt_Id;

private String tmode,cntNum,cntType;

public int getCnt_Id() {
    return cnt_Id;
}
  //corresponding getters and setters
}
```

HBSubclass code:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.*;
import org.hibernate.cfg.*;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Order;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;

import def.ContwithAnnotations;


public class HBSubclass {   

//entering data into table


public long saveContainer(int cnt_Id,String tmode,String cntNum,String cntType) {
    Session session = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure()
            .buildSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transaction = null;

    try {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        ContwithAnnotations hb = new ContwithAnnotations();         
        hb.setCnt_Id(cnt_Id);
        hb.setTmode(tmode);
        hb.setCntNum(cntNum);
        hb.setCntType(cntType);
        session.save(hb);
        transaction.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        transaction.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return cnt_Id;
}
//updating cont
public void updateContainer(int cnt_Id,String tmode,String cntNum,String cntType){


    Session session = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure()
            .buildSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transaction = null;
    try {


        transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        ContwithAnnotations hb = (ContwithAnnotations) session.get     (ContwithAnnotations.class, cnt_Id); 

        hb.setCnt_Id(cnt_Id);
        hb.setTmode(tmode);
        hb.setCntNum(cntNum);
        hb.setCntType(cntType);
        session.update(hb);
        transaction.commit();

        System.out.println(" updated\n"); 

    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        transaction.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    } 
} 

//deleting one row from table

public void deleteContainer(int cnt_Id){
    Session session = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure()
            .buildSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transaction = null;
    try {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        ContwithAnnotations hb = (ContwithAnnotations) session.get (ContwithAnnotations.class, cnt_Id);                     
        session.delete(hb);
        transaction.commit();
        System.out.println(" deleted\n");
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        transaction.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}  
}
```

Main code:

```
import abc.HBSubclass;
import java.util.*;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
public class ContMain {
public static void main(String[] args){
int cnt_Id=0;
String tmode=null;
String cntNum=null;
String cntType=null;

hb.saveContainer(12345,rail,cnt12345, rectangle);
hb.saveContainer(48956,ROAD,CNTR08112013, circle);
hb.saveContainer(12345,ocean,cnt478569, square);

hb.updateContainer(48956,"ROAD","CNTR08112013","adref"); // it is working good
hb.updateContainer(12345,"ROAD","CNTR08112013","adref"); // throwing error which shown in the begining
deleteContainer(48956);     //it is working fine
deleteContainer(12345);    // throwing error which shown in the begining
}
}
```

Could anyone help me how to fix this issue and where I am going wrong?.

Thanks in advance.

ven

Comment: you made your cnt_id and identifier of bean. This is expected behaviour. you are trying to insert record with same primary key.

Comment: Thanks Adi. Now i have changed primary key to some Long Id. Now the error is gone but still i am not able to update existing row if there are same rows in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Table:
cnt_Id  t   mode        cntNum           cntType
12345       rail        cnt12345         rectangle
48956       ROAD        CNTR08112013     circle
12345       ocean       cnt478569        square
```

From my understing primery key cannot de duplicated. but in your case the two rows has same value(12345). I dont understand how did you insert two rows with same primary key ids...
If i'm wrong in ur case please let me know...

Cheers!

Comment: Hi Balaji,it is not a primary key. So i am able to insert similar id's into the table.Thanks